# Does Java SE (J2SE) has something similar to AIDL in Android?

Tags: java

I want to implement a middleware in J2SE which provides services to more than one application running on the same host. How to implement this in J2SE? In Android, this can be done using AIDL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For desktop/server JavaSE environment, [Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish4.html) is a standard approach.

Comment: web services for IPC on the same host? I'd sooner use JMS or an EJB layer, better performance and less network traffic.

Comment: Indeed, in the SCRUM way of thinking that would be a better suggestion. Using a web service right off the bat has the possibility of more easily hooking up external systems too though. RIGHT NOW the guy wants to hook up something that is running on the same host. We all know how easily such things change.

Comment: Web service is not a good choice i think. Actually, more than one program pass data (eg. chat, file transfer) to one common program which encrypts the data and sends it to given IP address using socket programming. This common program also needs to receive data from the network, decrypt it and pass onto specific program. How can this be achieved in J2SE (Java Standard Edition) not J2EE.